# Selection contains a component introduced in an ancestor

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Is it possible delete or add new component inside free embracadero theme?

What is ancestor?

[image]

Comment: We can't see your code, so all I can do is assume that you are inheriting this form from another one. If you wish to delete it, delete from the root form, otherwise you can only hide it. Or don't introduce it in the root in the first place - just introduce it where you need it.

Answer (score 2):

`Ancestor`, in this context, means a class in the chain of classes from wich the object under discussion inherits. For example look at `TButton` in help. At the top of the help page, all ancestors of `TButton` are shown as a chain of classes starting with `TObject`

Thus, the error message means that an ancestor class (ancestor of your selection) has declared the component you try to delete.

If your version of Delphi comes with style files, you may modify them. I would copy the original style file to a safe place.

---

**Note**, that the structure view, left top of IDE, shows a different hierarchy that shouldn't be mixed with the class hierarchy. The parent - child chain (structure) indicates the components that hosts other components. E.g. A form can be a parent to a panel which might be the parent of a button. Or a grid panel that has collections of other components.

Comment: I use DX 10.3 Community. I'm install teme from Tools > Getit Package Manager. Where is location "original style file " which type (extensions) is that file? Maybe in my version is not possible edit theme!

Comment: I don't know for sure but I suspect that the Community version has limitations on using styles and/or manipulating them. The style files that come with the professional version are stored in`C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\Styles` (the 15.0 stands  for XE7, which I have installed on this machine). The file name extensions are `.vsf` or `.Style` depending on if they are for `VCL` or `FMX` projects.

Comment: The `rad-studio-feature-matrix.pdf`, that can be downloaded [from here](https://www.embarcadero.com/features/feature-matrix) doesn't seem to limit what you can do, or I just didn't find the right location in the doc.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you change the **View:** drop-down menu to **Master** you can delete the selected component(s).

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch to the Master View in order to delete components you dropped on the form.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **View: Master**
You have to switch to the Master View